# How to determine whether 2 code snippets are functionally same?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, language-features, feature-extraction

Given 2 code snippets I want to check whether they are functionally similar or not. By functional similarity I mean that they should yield same output when provided with same input.
I am extracting feature set from a given code snippet using :

1. **Syntactic Approach** : Using basic NLP techniques like stemming, splitting etc.
2. **Semantic Approach** : Using AST to normalize a code snippet eg : converting ‘for’ to ‘while’ etc.

After forming tokens, I am using topic modelling algorithms like Latent Dirichlet Allocation, probabilistic latent semantic indexing etc. for finding topics in a given code snippet and matching it with the other code snippet’s topic. Though I understand it’s a hard problem, the accuracy of the approach is much lower than I expected.

It would be great if I can get any pointers/ideas on better algorithms / techniques which will be more effective.

**Edit** : I am not looking forward for a generic approach. Any approach which gives approximate results with certain accuracy would do.

Answer (score 3):

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem - it's not possible to decide if a code snippet computes a specific function, so you also cannot decide if two code snippets compute the same function. So there can't be a general algorithm to achieve what you want. You may find something that will work in some cases or for a specific subset of whatever language, but never for the general case.

Comment: Yeah, I have read about it (Similar to halting problem). We don't need exact similar matches we want probabilistic approach which gives decent accuracy.

Comment: So you want an algorithm that takes two code snippets as input and want to decide whether they compute something similar - that's still a function - and you can't escape Rice's theorem. You may achieve an algorithm, given two code snippets, do they have the same normalized representation or the same normalized AST - but then you've left the general case. If you want a probabilistic approach by simulating or something like that - which part of the infinite set of inputs are you going to test?

Comment: For now, I will be happy if I'm able to get to a normalized representation of the code snippets. General case is definitely out of question.

Any leads on the normalized representation bit will be appreciated!

Comment: I strongly doubt that this can lead to something useful that goes beyond detecting simple renaming of variables (but maybe that's enough for you, then go the way you suggested yourself). You'd need not only normalization of arithmethic expressions (a * a - b * b will have to be equivalent to (a+b)*(a-b), a+a+a will have to be equivalent to 3*a, but also all kinds of optimization stuff like 1+2+...+n being the same as n*(n+1)/2 just to take some prominent mathematical simplifications. And then you're still far off anything simple like stripping the first iteration out of a for or while.

Comment: As an additional comment: just think of 4 different ways to decide whether a number is prime - the (normalized) representation of those 4 codes won't be similar at all - on the other hand, take a simple while (n>0) n--; loop vs. while (n>0) n++; loop (with an unsigned int n) - the normalized representation will be similar, but the computed function isn't similar at all. Maybe make your application/goal a bit more clear what you need and mean by "probabilistic approach with decent accuracy" - I'm sorry, but ignoring Rice's theorem is usually a time killer.